# echo -e working in terminal but not in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I developed and maintain a ruby gem called Githug and I am trying to write an automated test script for it.  Githug basically manipulates a directory to put it into different states of a working git repository and you can execute git commands to "solve" the level.

One of the levels asks you for your git config details and I am doing the following:

```
#! /bin/sh
# ...snip
#level 4
FULL_NAME=$(git config --get user.name)
EMAIL=$(git config --get user.email)
echo -e "$FULL_NAME\n$EMAIL" | githug
```

When I execute from a bash script it (echo -e) doesn't work.  But it does when I run it from the terminal.

```
FULL_NAME=$(git config --get user.name)
EMAIL=$(git config --get user.email)
echo -e "$FULL_NAME\n$EMAIL" | githug
********************************************************************************
*                                    Githug                                    *
********************************************************************************
What is your name? What is your email?
Congratulations, you have solved the level
```

Why doesn't this work from the bash script?

Thanks.

Comment: In this case, it's basically the `echo` equivalent of UUOC. Use `githug <<<"$FULL_NAME"$'\n'"$EMAIL"`, or a bit cleaner and more portable would be the `heredoc` equivalent. With a pipe there's a lot of extra forking and the "githug" is running in a subshell which might not be desirable.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out using that method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Wrong shebang:

```
#! /bin/sh
```

When it shall be a bash script, use

```
#! /bin/bash
```

Bash has a buildin echo, which isn't 100% identic with /bin/echo.

Comment: 11 minutes until I can accept this answer, but you are spot on.  Can't believe I didn't see that.

Comment: As an aside, just don't use `echo -e` or `-n` ever. Use `printf`, `printf '%b'`, or with bash or ksh, the `$''` special quoting.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, [`printf`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf) is the [preferred option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/7490), as illustrated in Git 2.14.x/2.15 (Q4 2017)

```
printf '%s\n%s' "$FULL_NAME" "$EMAIL"
```

See [commit 1a6d468](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1a6d46895d30459efe2d258c6e0a208f00f2b043) (17 Sep 2017) by [Torsten Bögershausen (`tboegi`)](https://github.com/tboegi).
<sup>(Merged by [Torsten Bögershausen -- `tboegi` --](https://github.com/tboegi) in [commit 1a6d468](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1a6d46895d30459efe2d258c6e0a208f00f2b043), 21 Sep 2017)</sup>

> ### `test-lint`: `echo -e` (or `-E`) is not portable
>
> Some implementations of `echo` support the '`-e`' option to enable
>   backslash interpretation of the following string.
>   As an addition, they support '`-E`' to turn it off.
>
> However, none of these are portable, POSIX doesn't even mention them,
>   and many implementations don't support them.
>
> A check for '`-n`' is already done in [`check-non-portable-shell.pl`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/20fed7cad40ed0b96232feb828129e3a2ee9860d/t/check-non-portable-shell.pl),
>   extend it to cover '`-n`', '`-e`' or '`-E`'.